# How can I uninstall linux form my removable drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, kubuntu

I put a Linux(Kubuntu) on my removable hard disk. I used the whole disk for it so I can not see it on Windows(If I can see disk I can reset it with *Rufus*). I want to use that disk again on ma windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 10:

1. Hit Windows+r
2. Type DISKMGMT.MSC and hit Enter
3. Locate your removable drive by its size or model/serial no. and delete any partitions on it if applicable
4. Format it to a FAT type if it's a flash drive, NTFS if it's a hard drive or SSD